# Do speakers using [ɪu] instead of /juː/ use “an” as the indefinite article before this?

Tags: dialects, indefinite-articles, phonology

There are quite some dialects that use vowel-beginning diphthongs like [ɪu] for what is /juː/ in the Received Pronunciation and General American dialects.

Do speakers of these dialects (tend to/want to) use *an,* not *a,* before words beginning with this diphthong, e.g., do they say:

> an university

Do they use *an* nearly all the time, sometimes, or about never? If they do use *a,* is there an explanation? Is there a pattern of distribution of the two forms of the singular indefinite article?

Comment: Please define RP&GA. It is very bad practice to use such specialized abbreviations without definition in a question.

Comment: I have never heard anyone pronounce initial /ju/ as [ɪu] in English. The sequence [ɪu], in fact, does not exist at all in any type of English that I'm familiar with, certainly neither RP nor GA. You'll have to provide some evidence that this variation exists at all; otherwise this is entirely hypothetical and unanswerable.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: It's well-documented that some accents such as Welsh have [ɪu] for "ue", "eu", "ew", "u_e", including in some places where RP has [u] such as "blue" and "rue". I don't know if this occurs word-initially, but if you know it doesn't, that would constitute an answer to this question. https://books.google.com/books?id=9jchAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT229&lpg=PT229&dq=Welsh+%5Bɪu&source=bl&ots=eG7311BdRW&sig=_7Sk6qAse3I1P4xbt-6WOg8s32g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-kM2_pJXRAhUQ5mMKHXKbD2UQ6AEIJDAC#v=onepage&q=Welsh%20%5Bɪu&f=false

Comment: @sumelic Initially? I've seen descriptions of certain Welsh dialects as distinguishing [uː] and [ɪʉ̯ ~ ʏʉ̯] postconsonantally, but I've never seen [ɪu] (with two full vowels), and I've seen no mention of this occurring initially. Searching around a bit, though, I do find it mentioned [here](https://books.google.dk/books?id=a3-ElL71fikC&pg=PA385&lpg=PA385), with even a mention of _an union_, so I guess it does occur initially as well. (And that source does also seemingly simplify the falling diphthong to [ɪu].)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: As I wrote, "I don't know if this occurs word-initially". It looks like you've found the answer; you should make a post out of that. I don't understand why you see  [ɪu] in the OP as indicating two full vowels; it seemed clear to me that it represents something like [ɪu̯], just as /aɪ/ is [aɪ̯] not [a.ɪ]. It is described as a  "vowel-beginning diphthong".

Comment: @sumelic Sorry, didn't see your edit until after I'd posted. If a glide [u̯] was intended in phonetic writing, it should be written. In phonemes it doesn't matter as much, because the glidification can occur closer to the surface, but in phonetic writing it seems an important detail to me. Especially in a Welsh context, since I believe some dialects of Welsh actually do distinguish [aɪ] and [aɪ̯] (though I have no idea whether that spills over into English as well). Plus you can't tell otherwise whether [ɪu] is [ɪu̯] or [ɪ̯u], a rising or a falling diphthong.

Comment: @sumelic The question said /iu/ until I fixed it.

Comment: @sumerlic (My edit was on the linguistics site before it was migrated here)

Answer (score 2):

In some American dialects, people only use [ɪu] for /juː/ when it doesn't start a word.

In my speech, I always use [ɪu]<sup>1</sup> after some consonants like /n/ and /l/. And I use [ɪu], [juː], or [uː] after other consonants. But words like *ewer*, *Ewing*, *university* always begin with [juː].

But if I ***did*** begin a word with [ɪu], I would definitely use *an*. If I try to say *a ewer* [ə ɪuər], it feels wrong, whereas *an ewer* [ən ɪuər] feels right.

<sup>1</sup>It's actually closer to [yu], where the first element of the diphthong is the French vowel in *tu*.